# Finish Main() from within sub class

Tags: java, terminate

I've got a Main() that gets executed as as Thread on a schedule.
If an exception happens (e.printStackTrace), the threads aborts and waits until the next starts.

I want to be able to abort the thread without throwing an exeption.
Inside the Main()-Class it's fairly easy, just "return false", and the thread ends.

But when I'm inside a Class/Object of a Class, I can't do that.
How can I abort/finish the Main from within a subclass?

Comment: Can you possibly show us some code so that we can have something tangible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to abort the Thread, or do you want to shutdown the VM?

If you want to stop the VM, try Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);

Stopping an arbitrary running thread is generally unsafe, try reading:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

to better explain the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you don't want to shutdown whole program, just some thread?

You need to return from all submethods you get in. Can you show how your method `run()` looks inside your threads?

For example: if you return from some function (`doSomething()`) you need to return from method `run()`:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        doSomething(); // - your main function
    }
}
```

Just check some condition. If you want to exit set value `boolean exiting = true;` and check it inside your loop: `if (exiting) return;`

The correct way to close any thread is just to return from method `run`

Answer (score -1):

You could try System.exit(0).

Let us know if that works.

Comment: I was under the impression that he didn't want to exit the whole program.